# Passing a value of an array to button C# WinForm

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I know about arrays. But I only know it using console, now I don't know how to implement it in windows form using visual studio, and I cannot saw anything online about what I wan't to do. Let's say for example I initialise an array of int:

```
int[] n = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Now what I want is, for example, there are 5 buttons, let's say when I click on button1, it will output:

```
MessageBox.Show("Number " + ... // random value in an array n
```

The same will happen to other 5 buttons but with no repetition. I know my question can be flagged as inappropriate but, I am asking this question since yesterday, an took a research the whole night but still nothing.

Comment: Use `Random` class to generate a valid array `index` postition, then write `MessageBox.Show("Number " + n[_random.Next(0,n.Length)]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to grab a random value from the array, then remove that value so that the other buttons can not show the same number.  A `List<int>` would be easier to work with.

```
private void formLoad(object sender, EventArgs e) {  
    // wire this handler up to your Form.Load event

    List<int> numbers = new List<int>() {101,22,373,414,625};
    Random random = new Random();

    Button1.Click += clickHandler;
    Button2.Click += clickHandler;
    Button3.Click += clickHandler;
    Button4.Click += clickHandler;
    Button5.Click += clickHandler;
}

private void clickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (0 == numbers.Count) { 
        MessageBox.Show("There are no more numbers in the list.");
        return;
    }
    int index = random.Next(0, numbers.Count);
    MessageBox.Show("Number " + numbers[index].ToString());
    numbers.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: This is really very nice solution. That's why i have deleted my answer. I don't want to misguide the OP when there is already good answer is posted. The only one thing is i would like to suggest is that rather than using `0` and `number.Count` in the `Next` method parameter. you can use Minimum value and maximum value of list. because the number from 0 to 3 are removed then still application will try to get next random number from between 0 and total count and also it may create problem when numbers are not serial. for example `{12, 245, 30, 5, 9}`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm getting an error on Button1.Click += clickHandler. I tried to type it below public Form1() {initiaizeComponent}

Comment: @AldrinRamirez did you place that code in Form load or in constructor after InitializeComponent method?

Comment: @Shell: The random.Next grabs an *index* from the list.  Then uses that index to grab the list element.  So the index will always, by definition, be from 0 to numbers.Count.  This way the values in the list can be anything, in any order (technically don't even have to be numbers, could be a List<string>, and it would still work.

Comment: @Shell: your method works too, and has the advantage of maintaining a history - if that feature is needed.  The method I proposed destroys the list (though you could add a second if you needed to store history).  I would propose you undelete your answer.  It provides a valid alternative and lets the OP compare methodologies.

Comment: Thanks for the more information about the `Next` method. I hope this will also help to OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest [Sam Axe's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203322/3761928) solution. it is very simple and easy to understand. The only reason to provide this solution is if you want to maintain the selected item history then this solution might be helpful for you.

You can stored the used value in a list which can be checked while next random 
number is being fetched.

To get the random integer number. You can use [Random.Next(int32, int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
int[] n = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<int> usedN = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();

private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    int iIndex = rnd.Next(0, n.Length-1);
    int iRnd = n[iIndex];

    if (usedN.Count == n.Length)
        return;

    usedN.Add(iRnd);
    MessageBox.Show("Number " + iRnd.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer has similarities to Sam Axe's answer, but was created independently. It may help someone. Code is available on https://github.com/zedfoxus/StackOverflow29203245

The form has 5 buttons and an extra button to reset the numbers after they are all used up.

### Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow29203245
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly List<int> _numbers  = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        private readonly List<int> _asked = new List<int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Select random integer from the list of integers. If no numbers are left, throw an exception
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Random integer from the list</returns>
        private int RandomInteger()
        {
            if (_numbers.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("All numbers have been selected");
            }

            var random = new Random();
            var index = random.Next(_numbers.Count);
            var selectedNumber = _numbers[index];
            _asked.Add(selectedNumber);
            _numbers.Remove(selectedNumber);
            return selectedNumber;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Show the message box. If all numbers are selected, show appropriate message
        /// </summary>
        private void ShowMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Number " + RandomInteger());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Reset numbers
        /// </summary>
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _numbers.AddRange(_asked);
            _asked.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use `_numbers.RemoveAt`, not `_numbers.Remove` - otherwise your code isn't matching the intent.   `RemoveAt` conveys intent.  If your list contained `{1,3,5,7,1,3}` and you call `.Remove(1)`, it will remove the first `1` and leave the others - which may or may not be what you intended to do.

Comment: Great point, @SamAxe. Thank you. I had indeed intended to use `_numbers.Remove(1)` to remove the first `1` in `{1,3,5,7,1,3}` in this example.